# Selenium Edge Browser not launching

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, edgedriver

I am using Selenium 4.6.0

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge()
driver.maximize_window
```

I am Receiving this

```
[13928:7924:0414/232444.891:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.
[13928:7924:0414/232444.931:ERROR:api_wrapper.cc(102)] Calling IsEnclaveTypeSupported, error code 0

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:61553/devtools/browser/4faa9355-ce13-45ef-8ffd-4049dfe84806
```

I hae tried many version and even tried it without webdriver manager

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE: It looks like this is caused by a classic update-the-software problem.

visit here to get the latest driver: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

then paste it into your directory, for me its here: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps

---

not an answer but I'm working on the same thing. found this in another thread. (need to take a break now)

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Answer (score 0):

A recent upgrade to some software (perhaps Edge) meant that my python Selenium code stopped working. When I looked at the error message, the first one I saw was the CBCM one from above:

```
[31104:44608:0418/104503.739:ERROR:chrome_browser_cloud_management_controller.cc(162)] Cloud management controller initialization aborted as CBCM is not enabled.

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/53a05bfa-3381-4f3c-9de2-d10cf03d943e
[31104:44608:0418/104504.194:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(767)] Rejected an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost:9222 origin. Use the command line flag --remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:9222 to allow connections from this origin or --remote-allow-origins=* to allow all origins.
[31104:44608:0418/104504.215:ERROR:devtools_http_handler.cc(767)] Rejected an incoming WebSocket connection from the http://localhost:9222 origin. Use the command line flag --remote-allow-origins=http://localhost:9222 to allow connections from this origin or --remote-allow-origins=* to allow all origins.
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

I started searching for this CBCM error and found this page.

But after some investigation, it turns out that this CBCM error was not preventing my system from working - it was one of the subsequent errors that was the real problem. The solution in this case was to add a new argument to my startup options:

```
    edge_options = Options()
    edge_options.add_argument("--remote-allow-origins=*")
    driver = webdriver.Edge(options=edge_options)
```